# Firebase query with startAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code

```
firebase.database().ref().child('Users').orderByChild('interest').
startAt('cat').endAt('cat'+'\uf8ff').
on('value',snap=>{
  console.log(snap.val())
})
```

[image: my database]

my code is that way but result is return null , How can I  access data?

Comment: The child `interest` doesn't have a string value, so no child nodes match the `startAt` and `endAt` criteria. The Firebase query language does not allow filtering array value like that. So while your current data structure is great for efficiently loading the interests for a specific user, it does not allow efficient loading of the users for a specific interest. For that you'll want to add a so-called inverted data structure: `/Interests/$interest` with the user IDs of the users who have that interest. Also see my answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40656589/

Answer (score 0):

get methods:

```
getUsers() {
 firebase.database().ref('Users')
  .once('value')        
  .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())    
  .then(users => console.log(users));
}
```

Comment: This is for all users but I dont want to list all user,I want to list interest= start ca,cat,cats users

Comment: Here is an example, Replace it as you want.

Comment: Read this Doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write